# Replace value with NaN based on previous and subsequent values in the time series

Tags: python, pandas, replace, time-series

I am working with python pandas and a huge dataframe with multiple time series similar to the following dataframe consisting of three time series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Year': [2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013],
'Week': [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
'Location': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
'Amount': [None, None, None, None, None, 46, None, None, None, 55, None, None, None, None, None,29, 24, 65, 34, 34, 34, 23, 87, 56, 89, 23, 45, 63, 87, 89]})
```

```
    Year  Week  Location  Amount
0   2012    48         1     NaN
1   2012    49         1     NaN
2   2012    50         1     NaN
3   2012    51         1     NaN
4   2012    52         1     NaN
5   2013     1         1    46.0
6   2013     2         1     NaN
7   2013     3         1     NaN
8   2013     4         1     NaN
9   2013     5         1    55.0
10  2012    48         2     NaN
11  2012    49         2     NaN
12  2012    50         2     NaN
13  2012    51         2     NaN
14  2012    52         2     NaN
15  2013     1         2    29.0
16  2013     2         2    24.0
17  2013     3         2    65.0
18  2013     4         2    34.0
19  2013     5         2    34.0
20  2012    48         3    34.0
21  2012    49         3    23.0
22  2012    50         3    87.0
23  2012    51         3    56.0
24  2012    52         3    89.0
25  2013     1         3    23.0
26  2013     2         3    45.0
27  2013     3         3    63.0
28  2013     4         3    87.0
29  2013     5         3    89.0
```

**For each time series, I want to change the Amount in Year 2013 Week 1 to NaN if the three weeks before and the three weeks after are NaNs**.

The result should look like this (Amount is NaN now in Year 2013, Week 1, Location 1):

```
    Year  Week  Location  Amount
0   2012    48         1     NaN
1   2012    49         1     NaN
2   2012    50         1     NaN
3   2012    51         1     NaN
4   2012    52         1     NaN
5   2013     1         1     NaN
6   2013     2         1     NaN
7   2013     3         1     NaN
8   2013     4         1     NaN
9   2013     5         1    55.0
10  2012    48         2     NaN
11  2012    49         2     NaN
12  2012    50         2     NaN
13  2012    51         2     NaN
14  2012    52         2     NaN
15  2013     1         2    29.0
16  2013     2         2    24.0
17  2013     3         2    65.0
18  2013     4         2    34.0
19  2013     5         2    34.0
20  2012    48         3    34.0
21  2012    49         3    23.0
22  2012    50         3    87.0
23  2012    51         3    56.0
24  2012    52         3    89.0
25  2013     1         3    23.0
26  2013     2         3    45.0
27  2013     3         3    63.0
28  2013     4         3    87.0
29  2013     5         3    89.0
```

What I tried does not work:

```
df.loc[((df['Year'] == 2012) & (df['Week'] == 50) & (df['Amount'] == None)) &
       ((df['Year'] == 2012) & (df['Week'] == 51) & (df['Amount'] == None)) &
       ((df['Year'] == 2012) & (df['Week'] == 52) & (df['Amount'] == None)) &
       ((df['Year'] == 2013) & (df['Week'] == 1) & (df['Amount'] >= 0)) &
       ((df['Year'] == 2013) & (df['Week'] == 2) & (df['Amount'] == None)) &
       ((df['Year'] == 2013) & (df['Week'] == 3) & (df['Amount'] == None)) &
       ((df['Year'] == 2013) & (df['Week'] == 4) & (df['Amount'] == None)), 'Amount'] = None
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Why are you doing `== None`? First, comparisons to None should be done using `is None`, and second, there are no None values in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`rolling.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.sum.html) with [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) and [`Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) 
to create a mask and apply it with [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
m = (df['Amount'].notna()
                 .groupby(df['Location'])
                 .rolling(7,center = True).sum().le(1)
                 .reset_index(level = 'Location',drop='Location'))
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].mask(m & df['Year'].eq(2013) & df['Week'].eq(1))
print(df)

    Year  Week  Location  Amount
0   2012    48         1     NaN
1   2012    49         1     NaN
2   2012    50         1     NaN
3   2012    51         1     NaN
4   2012    52         1     NaN
5   2013     1         1     NaN
6   2013     2         1     NaN
7   2013     3         1     NaN
8   2013     4         1     NaN
9   2013     5         1    55.0
10  2012    48         2     NaN
11  2012    49         2     NaN
12  2012    50         2     NaN
13  2012    51         2     NaN
14  2012    52         2     NaN
15  2013     1         2     NaN
16  2013     2         2    24.0
17  2013     3         2    65.0
18  2013     4         2    34.0
19  2013     5         2    34.0
20  2012    48         3    34.0
21  2012    49         3    23.0
22  2012    50         3    87.0
23  2012    51         3    56.0
24  2012    52         3    89.0
25  2013     1         3     NaN
26  2013     2         3    45.0
27  2013     3         3    63.0
28  2013     4         3    87.0
29  2013     5         3    89.0
```

**For new dataframe:**

```
df.assign(Amount = df['Amount'].mask(m & df['Year'].eq(2013) & df['Week'].eq(1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
s = pd.Series(df['Amount'].isna()
                  .groupby(df['Location'])
                  .rolling(7,center=True)
                  .sum().values,
              index=df.index)

df.loc[(s.ge(6)& df['Year'].eq(2013) 
        & df['Week'].eq(1) & df['Amount'].notna()), 'Amount'] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
    Year  Week  Location  Amount
0   2012    48         1     NaN
1   2012    49         1     NaN
2   2012    50         1     NaN
3   2012    51         1     NaN
4   2012    52         1     NaN
5   2013     1         1     NaN
6   2013     2         1     NaN
7   2013     3         1     NaN
8   2013     4         1     NaN
9   2013     5         1    55.0
10  2012    48         2     NaN
11  2012    49         2     NaN
12  2012    50         2     NaN
13  2012    51         2     NaN
14  2012    52         2     NaN
15  2013     1         2    29.0
16  2013     2         2    24.0
17  2013     3         2    65.0
18  2013     4         2    34.0
19  2013     5         2    34.0
20  2012    48         3    34.0
21  2012    49         3    23.0
22  2012    50         3    87.0
23  2012    51         3    56.0
24  2012    52         3    89.0
25  2013     1         3    23.0
26  2013     2         3    45.0
27  2013     3         3    63.0
28  2013     4         3    87.0
29  2013     5         3    89.0
```